# What was the purpose of the "tail prop" on the Ilyushin Il-62 and why was it necessary?

Tags: aircraft-design, il-62

I read somewhere that the Ilyushin Il-62 had a "tail prop".  What was this device and why was it needed on this aircraft?

Comment: I read "prop" as propeller at first.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Are you asking about the rear support wheel? It is for supporting the aircraft and avoiding tilt on the ground.
[image]
<sup>Image from wikimedia commons. Autor:M Radzi Desa</sup>

As the aircraft had four engines in the aft, the cg would've been aft too; so they added a tail prop to prevent tilt on ground.

Interestingly, this doesn't seen to be unique for Il-62. Another aircraft with rear mounted engine, Sud Aviation Caravelle, has something similar to this. 
[image]
<sup>Image from wikimedia commons. Author: Eduard Marmet</sup>

Comment: in case of the Caravelle it's actually not a support structure but a rear staircase. Early model B727s had one as well.

Comment: Looks like a number of tail engines aircrafts like DC 9 and Yak 42 have this 'airstairs'. They double up as tail support while loading, I guess.

Comment: they don't. They lack the structural strength and aren't rigidly attached to anything. They're in fact spring mounted to allow for easy manual extension and storage,

Comment: @jwenting I'm not sure aeroalias speak of the stairs. On the picture you may see a vertical structure just before the stairs. It may be something behind the aircraft but may also be a support. I really don't know, any reference would be welcome

Comment: @ManuH From looking closely at it, including the shadows, it does appear to be attached to the plane, rather than something behind it. My assumption was also that that's what the answer was referring to.

Comment: I'm pretty sure a secondary purpose of aiistairs was to support the tail during loading. Back in the day when we used 727's at FedEx the rear stairs were always down during loading & unloading. It doesn't have to support the whole weight of the plane, just whatever amount of differential in CG that was behind the rear wheels until finished loading. The other option, which was used on DC10's was a nose gear tether.

Comment: When I look at the shadows on that shot it looks more like it is behind the plane. I can't find any other photos of the Caravelle that show it. [Here](http://www.airlinebuzz.com/chickenworks/Images/DFW_080917_14.jpg) is a shot of tail stands being used on a couple types of aircraft. The unique thing about the Ilyushin is that it seems to be built into the aircraft itself.

Answer (score 18):

The 'tail prop' is more accurately described as a tail support. I remember seeing these on Il-62s at Heathrow in the 70s. They were deployed as the aircraft arrived at the gate, and retracted just before pushback.

Anecdotally, the aircraft had a propensity to tilt backwards and strike the tail on the ground during loading and unloading operations as the CG moved. The tail support eliminated this possibility.

[image]

Answer (score 13):

They're called "tail stands" for planes such as the Cessna Caravan.

During loading and unloading the CG can be tail-heavy enough that the aircraft would otherwise fall back on its tail.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

I found an Aircraft Operations Manual for IL-62 and IL-62 M of former GDR carrier Interflug (in German language):

- http://www.interflug.biz/IL-62%20Flugbetriebsdokumentationen.htm
- http://www.interflug.biz/Flugzeuge/IL-62/Handbuecher/FZH_Il62.pdf

According to this manual, the "tail prop" supports several functions.

- Supporting parked airplane while centre of gravity isn't controlled: The manual requires to extend the tail prop when parking, before opening any door. Tail prop shall be retracted only after closing all doors and only when centre of gravity is within limits (4.2.5. No. 2., tab. 4.2.5./1).
- Taxi with extended tail prop is allowed, speed limit is 25 km/h. (4.2.2. No. 1)
- When towing an empty plane the tail prop must be extended, speed limit is 15 km/h. (4.2.2. No. 2)
- Moving the plane backward by utilizing reverse thrust: Tail prop must be extended, speed limit is "walking pace". (4.2.2. No. 4)
- U-turn on a narrow runway (min. 45 m) by utilizing reverse thrust: Tail prop must be partly extended. (4.2.2. No. 5, fig. 4.2.2./2)

The tail prop features two self-steering wheels and a suspension system. No brakes, no active steering. It is extended and retracted by an electric motor, backed by a hand crank. (4.1.8. No. 1.3, fig. 4.1.8./5)

Probably, the tail prop is also designed to provide some protection in case of a tail strike (since it's wheels partly remain outside fuselage), but this function isn't mentioned in the manual.

Btw., this plane features a 3700 ℓ water tank (just behind the front landing gear bay), for adjusting centre of gravity in some low-load situations. (4.1.24., 4.3.2. No. 2.5, fig. 4.1.2/2 item 5)

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE!

Comment: Excellent find and well done in providing excerpts from the docs!

Answer (score 6):

It's a tail stand -- it prevents the airplane from tipping up and back onto its tailfeathers in a most embarrassing fashion, even if you have to load it back to front or unload it front to back (image from [Aerospaceweb's question on landing gear](http://www.aerospaceweb.org/question/design/q0200.shtml)):

[image: an ACA 747 tipped on its tail]

Answer (score 2):

Improvised tail-props were a feature of early, tricycle landing gear, military aircraft. Grumman's F7F Tigercat, certainly. There are photos with 55 gallon drums + assorted odds and ends as props, in place, and also photos of unsupported planes sitting with nose-wheels off the ground...

At that point in Grumman's history, nobody would have expected resting the tail on the ground would do any damage to the airplane...

Answer (score 2):

This is a very interesting take on CG vs Clift, in this case while the aircraft is not moving!
The wheels are holding the aircraft up.  It would take a relatively small amount of force to tip the plane onto its tail while loading or unloading.  A little like a table with 3 legs instead of 4.

While taking off, the aircraft has to be able to rotate, which means the main gear need to be only slightly aft of the CG when fueled and loaded for flight. On the ground this creates the potential for it to go "tail dragger" if cargo is removed from the front or added to the back.  Moving people from front to back was actually used in airships to help trim CG.

But it is very, very important to realize this is not done "because engines are heavy" and the designed CG is somehow unsafely aft.  Jet engines are actually (lb weight per lb thrust) much lighter than their piston counterparts.  Aircraft with swept wings who must, by necessity, mount the landing gear closer to the fuselage (or in the fuselage) would have a greater tendency for "ground Clift" issues.  The B52 designers solved this by mounting the wing at a higher AOA than the fuselage and taking off WITHOUT rotating, relying only on speed to lift the aircraft off.  This also fits well in pilot training not to "pull up" a large aircraft, as shear mass would make recovery of precious airspeed difficult, even with lots of excess
thrust available.

The "tail pogo" is strictly a safety precaution while passengers, cargo, and fuel are being loaded or unloaded on the ground,

Answer (score 1):

Many smaller turboprops and piston twins use 'tail props' or 'pogo-sticks' as they are known here.  Certainly Twin Otters, BN Islander and Trislanders use them.  Can't comment on the Caravan.  The last one I was son a few weeks ago had floats ;-)

Comment: welcome to aviation.se! please consider adding more details, currently you provide interesting information, but you do not actually answer the question "what is its purpose"

Answer (score 1):

Robert DiGiovanni's response is correct.

While the empty IL62 is a bit tail heavy, once the airplane is laoded with passengers/bags and cargo the CG will be moved forward. Look at how much longer the fwd fuselage is compared to the aft section, its around 4 times longer!

The MD11 has a similar proportion where the forward fuselage is much longer than the front. I've done the load-sheet for MD11 freighters and while the empty CG is VERY tail heavy, with a full load the CG is usually at the fwd limit.